# No value at JSON path

Tags: unit-testing, spring-mvc, mockito, jsonpath, mockmvc

How to write mockMVC test for the below JSON which has combination of String and Array.

```
{
  "id":1,
  "firstName":"NPA",
  "lastName":"TAS",
  "mobile":"123454321",
  "email":"ABCD@GMAIL.COM",
  "accounts":[
         {
          "id":1,
          "balance":"$1000",
          "custid":"1",
          "accNbr":"12345"
         }
            ]
}
```

My code:

```
@Test
        public void testJson() throws Exception {
            mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
            mockMvc.perform(get("/acc/1")
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.accounts.id", Matchers.is(1)))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.accounts.balance", Matchers.is("$1000")))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.accounts.accNbr", Matchers.is("12345")))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.accounts.custid", Matchers.is("1")))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.*", Matchers.hasSize(4)));
        }
```

i get the exception

No value at JSON path "$.accounts.id", exception:

> Expected to find an object with property ['accounts'] in path $ but found 'net.minidev.json.JSONArray'. This is not a json object according to the JsonProvider: 'com.jayway.jsonpath.spi.json.JsonSmartJsonProvider'.

However, if i try using $.accounts[0].id i get exception

No value at JSON path "$.accounts[0].id", exception:

> Expected to find an object with property ['accounts'] in path $ but found 'net.minidev.json.JSONArray'. This is not a json object according to the JsonProvider: 'com.jayway.jsonpath.spi.json.JsonSmartJsonProvider'.

Comment: Because there is an array of accounts. So, you should use $.accounts[0].id for the first account in your array accounts.

Comment: @KeyMarker00 $.accounts[0].id also not working

Comment: If you use the JSON supplied in your question in the [online evaulator](https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/) with this expression `$.accounts[0].id` then you **will** get a valid answer so the likeliest explanation for this: "@KeyMarker00 $.accounts[0].id also not working" is that the JSON prouced by `get("/acc/1")` does not match the JSON you included in your question. I suspect the actula JSON produced by that endpoint might look like this: `[{"id":1, "firstName":"NPA", ...}]` i.e. an array of subdocuments each containing an accounts[] rather than a single document containing an accounts[].

Answer (score 5):

As @glytching and I have mentioned, there is an array and it should work with `$.accounts[0].id`.

If you still encounter a problem, I would try to print the result your console:

```
MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
         .get("/acc/1").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andReturn();

String content = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();
```

Answer (score 4):

The `accounts` attribute is an array so this: `$.accounts.id` would have to use an indexer such as: `$.accounts[0].id`.

From the [docs](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath):

```
[<number> (, <number>)]     Array index or indexes
```

If you are uncertain about which index to use then you can filter the JSON and assert on the filtered account sub document. For example:

- `$.accounts[?(@.id == 1)].balance`: returns `$1000`
- `$.accounts[?(@.accNbr == 12345)].id`: returns `1`
- ... etc

Plenty more details in the [docs](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) and you can use the use the [JsonPath evaluator](https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/) to play around with this.